# How to load a XAML file in another XAML file

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I would like to be able to dynamically load a XAML file (or a control belonging to another XAML file, like a grid for example) into a control of the current page. For example and schematically:

In Page1.xaml:

```
<Grid Name=HelloGrid>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello">
</Grid>
```

In Page2.xaml:

```
<Grid>
   //part where I load Page1.xaml or just HelloGrid
</Grid>
```

Thanks for your time,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do `composite` xaml and not loading them. You can try creating a usercontrol for your Page1.xaml that contains given `a` prefix is defined in your `xaml` files

**CustomControl.xaml**

```
<Grid Name=HelloGrid>
   <TextBlock Text="Hello">
</Grid>
```

And on your Page1 and Page2 xaml

You can do

**Page1.xaml**

`<a:CustomControl/>`

and

**Page2.xaml**

```
<Grid>
  <a:CustomControl/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example please? What is "a"?